# aysnc priorityQueue - is a higher number higher priority?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, priority-queue

In the [caolan/async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.priorityQueue) library, what defines order for priority in `priorityQueue`? Is `1` first (highest) priority, or is a larger numeric value a higher priority?

The docs simply say the priority should be a number:

> push(task, priority, [callback]) - priority should be a number. If an
>   array of tasks is given, all tasks will be assigned the same priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the document you referenced:

> The same as async.queue only tasks are assigned a priority and **completed in ascending priority order**.

*(emphasis added)*

That means that lower numbers will come first.